# Check if elemntFromPoint() bumps into a hyperlink

Tags: javascript

I am using elemntFromPoint in order to return onclick some element. I would like to check if the returned element ('span' div' whatever...) is part of a link or if it is a button etc. How should I start? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the element "is part of a link" you'll want to traverse up the DOM tree until you hit an anchor - if you don't hit an anchor then the element isn't in a link. E.g.

```
var el = document.elementFromPoint(x,y),
    cur = el,
    isInAnchor = false;

do {
    if (cur.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
        isInAnchor = true;
        break;
    }
} while (cur = cur.parentNode);

alert(isInAnchor); // either true or false
```